# Combine cross-entropy and mse in loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a regression problem. My dataset has labels ranging from `[0,1]`. Due to the design purpose, the label with the value over `0.3` is converted to the negative, i.e., `0.35` is converted to `-0.35`.

In keras, I first tried `mse` as the loss function, but the performance is not good. After I realize the sign of labels, I tried binary cross-entropy as well. But the performance is still not good.

As I explained above, it seems we can utilize two loss functions and sum them up. But I don't know how to write the code. Besides, if you have any other suggestion for this specific dataset, please let me know.

Comment: Did you try mean absolute error(mae)? Also, binary cross-entropy is for classification problems, not regression problems.

Comment: @semicolon in the past couple days I tried DNN. The performance metrics I focus is sign accuracy. Of course, the predicted values are also important. With `mse` and DNN structure, the current sign accuracy is 81.5%. I tried your suggestion with `mae` as loss function and the same DNN structure. The sign accuracy is 81.7%. The answer given by Julio below is almost what I want, though an error is raised. Actually, the reason I want to introduce cross entropy is to improve the sign accuracy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own loss function, checkout [keras documentation](https://keras.io/losses/) and [source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py) for ideas, but it should be something like this:

```
from keras.losses import mean_squared_error, binary_crossentropy

def my_custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    mse = mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
    crossentropy = binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    return mse + crossentropy

...

model.compile(loss=my_custom_loss, ...)
```

Also checkout the [backend API](https://keras.io/backend/) to use primitives if you need basic tensor operations

Comment: There is an error: `TypeError: custom_loss() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`. And I compile model as this `model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=self.custom_loss, metrics=['mse'])`

Comment: `self` is the third parameter, that is why is giving you an error

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the Keras functional api to build a multi output model.

You could create one output for the classification part of the model and one output for the regression part of the model. (FYI, in literature these are referred to as the classification head and regression head of the CNN.)

Then you can specify the loss functions for each of the outputs.

You can also weight each loss function (i.e. set weights for linear combination of losses of each of the models outputs).

This type of multi output model is explained in [Keras functional api guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).  Read through the link and pay attention to the section **Multi-input and multi-output models**